# C# XML Serialization, Can I serialize List<T>?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am looking for an XML Serialization solution to serialize a class which contains a `List<T>`. Reading [the MSDN article for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) `System.XML.Serialiation` it states (about 5/8 down the page)

```
[Serialization of ArrayList and Generic List]
The XmlSerializer cannot serialize or deserialize the following: 
  Arrays of ArrayList
  Arrays of List<T>
```

Does this mean I cannot serialize my `List<T>` or does this say I cannot serialize something like

```
List<int>[] intArr = new List<int>[10];
```

EDIT: Why isn't it possible to do so?

Comment: you should be able to serialize List<T>, i think this is meant for cascading datatypes

Comment: It means exactly what it says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array of list will be

```
List<int>[]
```

So, you can safely serialize

```
List<int>
```

Answer (score 1):

The latter. Serializing `List<T>` is very common.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whole class, or just the List:

```
static void SerializeToXml<T>(string file, T value)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(file))
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
}

static T DeserializeFromXml<T>(string file)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(file))
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```